# Excel: Sum Values in a Column for Rows Where a Particular Value is Matched in a Corresponding Cell

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, vlookup

I have two sheets in Excel: (1) one with the data I'm continually adding to and (2) one that reports on a variety of metrics.

I want to use a formula in (2) to display conditional counts of data in (1). The formula should show the sum of numerical values from a column (T) when the corresponding row values in another column (B) match a value from sheet (2).

The values in column B vary. I'm also continuing to add data to sheet (1), so I can't specify different arrays for each column (B) value I'm trying to look up.

For example, in the picture below, I want to return the count of values from column D that correspond to values in column A when the value in column A matches the value in another cell on a separate sheet. So, on a separate sheet, when the cell matched appropriately, "Josh" would return "2", "Karen" would return "1", and "Brad" also "1".

[This isn't the data I'm actually working on, but I think it demonstrates the concept.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBWBH.jpg)

I've tried combinations of vLookup, Dsum, Sumproduct, with IF statements. I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing. Help!

Comment: Did you try COUNTIF or COUNTIFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that you are missing something obvious, which is the [COUNTIFS](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php) and [SUMIFS](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumifs.php) functions.  I think that, now that you have heard of them, you should be able to try using them and get what you need.

Use `COUNTIFS`, for example, to count the number of cells in column B that match what is in, say, cell E1:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,E1)
```

So, `=COUNTIFS(B:B, "Some Data")` from your example would return 4.  You can add multiple criteria if you want; so, `=COUNTIFS(B:B, "Some Data", A:A, "Karen")` from your example would return 2 (there are only 2 rows with both "Some Data" **and** "Karen").

Use `SUMIFS`, for example, to sum column D where the value in column A matches what is in, say, cell E1:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,E1)
```

So, `=SUMIFS(D:D, "Josh")` from your example would return 2. You can add multiple criteria if you want; so, `=SUMIFS(D:D, "Josh", C:C, "Data")` from your example would return 1 (there is only 1 row with both "Josh" **and** "Data", and that row's value is 1).

Comment: Ah, you're a genius! Thank you!

As a quick follow up, is it possible instead of summing the values to return a count of (1) if the cell is not blank?

Instead of having the right-most column be a series of 1s and 0s, I'd rather count the number of times the cell is not blank. (Currently the 1s and 0s are a COUNTA of the adjacent column.) When I've tried to use =COUNTA nested it counts everything in a range instead of just the corresponding rows.

Comment: @John192150 How about something like `=COUNTIFS(B:B,E1,D:D,"<>"&"")` to count if column B is equal to E1 **and** column D is not equal to "" (two quotes- an empty string).

Comment: I think that gets it. Thank you so very much! I appreciate your time.